# Why can readonly array attributes on a Raku class be modified?

Tags: class, oop, raku, rakudo

Why can readonly array attributes be modified on a Raku class, but on the other hand, scalars cannot be modified?

How can I make `@.baz` "readonly"?

```
class Boo {
    has $.bar;
    has @.baz;
};

my $boo = Boo.new;

$boo.baz = (1, 2); # works ... ?
say $boo.baz;

$boo.bar = 1; #fails ... expected
```

My rakudo version:

```
This is Rakudo version 2020.05.1 built on MoarVM version 2020.05
implementing Raku 6.d.
```

Comment: Just guessing... Is this because `$boo.baz = (1, 2);` is not really creating a new array and assigning its reference to `baz`? Perhaps this `$boo.baz = (1, 2);` is internally doing something like `remove_elements_from_baz; baz.push: 1; baz.push: 2`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `baz` attribute is read only.

The thing is that the `baz` attribute is an `Array` which has mutable elements.

---

When you call `$boo.baz` you basically get a reference to the array.

Once you have a reference to the array you can do anything that you could normally do to the array.

```raku
say $boo.baz.VAR.name; # @!baz
```

When you assign to an array, what you are really doing is telling the array that it will have new contents.

```raku
my @a = ('a','b','c');
say @a.WHICH; # Array|94070988080608

@a = (1, 2, 3);
say @a.WHICH; # Array|94070988080608
```

Notice that the `.WHICH` doesn't change. That is because it is still the same array. It just has new contents.

The exact same thing happens when you assign to a public array attribute.
You are not assigning a new array, you are altering the existing one.

All of the behaviours of a variable are not intrinsic to the variable, they are instead handled by an object.
In the case of arrays the object that handles the assignment is `Array`.

---

The simplest fix is to just overload the autogenerated accessor method.

```raku
class Boo {
    has $.bar;
    has @.baz;

    method baz () { @!baz.List }
}
```

If you never plan on changing the values in @!baz you could make it a List itself

```raku
class Boo {
    has $.bar;
    has @.baz is List;
}
```

Comment: I think the confusion isn't why you can edit the elements — that's explained fairly easily by the object being internally mutable, but consider `class A {has @.a is List}; my $a = A.new(a=>(1,2)); $a.a = (3,4)`  The reference isn't being changed, even though it looks like I'm attempting to assign a brand new list to it. Instead, a listy assignment is done, with an apparent attempt at keeping the original referent intact

Comment: Yes, the `$boo.baz[0] = 9;` was expected. I Should have removed it from the question, sorry. I don't quite understand why can I assign a new list/array to the attribute

Comment: @Julio The answer is that you aren't assigning a new list or array. You are telling the existing array that it should have new contents.

Comment: @Julio you can see it's readonly by trying to bind it to another value: `class Boo { has @.bar }; Boo.new.bar := (33) ` will yield `OUTPUT: «===SORRY!=== Error while compiling <tmp>␤Cannot use bind  operator with this left-hand side␤`

Answer (score 0):

My vote goes to the 'is List' version suggested by @BradGilbert ... I tried it with defaults and got this Awesome Error message:

```
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling ...
Defaults on compound attribute types not yet implemented. Sorry.
Workaround: Create/Adapt TWEAK method in class Boo, e.g:

    method TWEAK() {
        @!baz := (initial values) unless @!baz;
    }
```